# library not found for -lAsyncDisplayKit

Tags: ios, cocoapods, asyncdisplaykit

In my project I get the following error in Xcode:

> library not found for -lAsyncDisplayKit

My project was configured with `pod`.

Can anyone help me fix it?

Comment: Set build active architectures to No for all targets.

Comment: i am not got solution for this error. in my terminal show message that all pods are installed. however i am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html) you can find some FAQ to resolve main issues with Cocoapods. You have also to check the architecture for the single project and target. If you use a different architecture, Xcode doesn't compile the others and so it will never find the libs

Answer (score 0):

After run `pod install` or `pod update` you **must use** the **new** `<YourProject>.xcworkspace` file instead of the old `<YourProject>.xcodeproj` file.

It happens because `.xcworkspace` contains your `.xcodeproj` and the `pods`.

After that you should be able to run normally.